# Contact Form not showing error messages or sending email

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Before I get into it I would like to say that this did send emails from my local server so I have everything set up. After adding this form validation it no longer sends emails or shows errors. It just refreshes the page. I'm new to php coding so I'm sure I just have an if statement in the wrong order or something like that.

HTML

```
<section id="contact">
            <h1 class="section-header">Contact Us Directly</h1>
            <h4 class="text-center">Have any quesitons not answered in the <span><a href="questions.php">Questions Page</a></span>.</h4>
            <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
                <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" value="<?php $firstname ?>" placeholder="Your name.." tabindex="1" autofocus>
                <span class="error"><?php $firstname_error ?></span>
                <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" value="<?php $lastname ?>" placeholder="Your last name.." tabindex="2">
                <span class="error"><?php $lastname_error ?></span>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php $email ?>" placeholder="Your email.." tabindex="3">
                <span class="error"><?php $email_error ?></span>
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea id="subject" name="message" value="<?php $message ?>" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px" tabindex="4"> </textarea>
                <span class="error"><?php $message_error ?></span>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="5"> 
                <span class="success"><?php $success ?></span>
            </form>
        </section>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$firstname_error = $lastname_error = $email_error = $message_error = "";
$firstname = $lastname = $email = $message = $success = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
    $firstname_error = "First name is required";
  } else {
    $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname)) {
      $firstname_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

    if (empty($_POST["lastname"])) {
    $lastname_error = "Last name is required";
  } else {
    $lastname = test_input($_POST["lastname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastname)) {
      $lastname_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message = "";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }


if ($firstname_error == '' and $lastname_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $message_error == '' ){
      $message_body = '';
      unset($_POST['submit']);
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
          $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
      }

      $EmailFrom = localhost;
      $EmailTo = "testrepairmail69@gmail.com";
      $Subject = "New Order From tabletscreenfixer.com";
      if (mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $message)){
          $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
          $firstname = $lastname = $email = $message = '';
      }
  }

}



function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Code is begging for some improvements as @R Smith mentioned; nevertheless this version works; i have tested on my pc. [image: check the image]

```
 <?php

  $firstname_error = $lastname_error = $email_error = $message_error = "";
  $firstname = $lastname = $email = $message = $success = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
    $firstname_error = "First name is required";
  } else {
    $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname)) {
        $firstname_error = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["lastname"])) {
    $lastname_error = "Last name is required";
} else {
    $lastname = test_input($_POST["lastname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastname)) {
        $lastname_error = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
} else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $email_error = "Invalid email format";
    }
}

if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message = "";
} else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
}


if ($firstname_error == '' and $lastname_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $message_error == '' ){
    $message_body = '';
    unset($_POST['submit']);
   // var_dump($_POST); exit();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
        $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
    }
    $EmailFrom = "test@gamil.com";
    $EmailTo = "tabletscreenfixer.com";//-> the message will be sent to this address if you have configure mail stuff well
    $Subject = "New Order From tabletscreenfixer.com";
    if (mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $message)){
        $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
        $firstname = $lastname = $email = $message = '';
    }else{
        echo "Failure";
    }
 }else{
    echo "Failure 2";
   }
 }
    function test_input($data) {
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;
    }
 ?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="contact">
    <h1 class="section-header">Contact Us Directly</h1>
    <h4 class="text-center">Have any quesitons not answered in the <span><a href="questions.php">Questions Page</a></span>.</h4>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname ?>" placeholder="Your name.." tabindex="1" autofocus>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $firstname_error ?></span>
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname ?>" placeholder="Your last name.." tabindex="2">
        <span class="error"><?php echo $lastname_error ?></span>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>" placeholder="Your email.." tabindex="3">
        <span class="error"><?php echo $email_error ?></span>
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea id="subject" name="message" value="<?php echo $message ?>" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px" tabindex="4"> </textarea>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $message_error ?></span>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="5">
        <span class="success"><?php $success ?></span>
    </form>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** Missing echo in the input value attribute;
Hope it helps;

Comment: Hey sorry it took so long to reply my power went out anywayyyyy. When I use your code instead of the page just reloading and nothing happening now it gives me a 403 error Acess Forbidden!

Comment: The page reloads because it sends the request to itself; you may need to remove this line :   unset($_POST['submit']);

Comment: Even after that it still reloads I just can't figure out why its doing this

Comment: Now it says that the variables in value fields aren't declared

Comment: They are declared at the top of script.

Comment: Oh I've moved past that I've just gotten rid of them I'm just gunna try to get the php to work or I might just got back to my old code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138878/discussion-between-lazy-coder-and-cosmichero-2025).

Answer (score 1):

Add some debugging.  For example, everywhere you have an error, increment a error counter.  Something like this:

```
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
  $email_error = "Email is required";
  $errors++;
} else {
  $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  // check if e-mail address is well-formed
  if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
  }
}
```

Then, at the end, instead of the long if condition:

```
if ($firstname_error == '' and $lastname_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $message_error == '' ){
```

You can use something like:

```
if ($errors == 0){
```

Which indicates no errors.  Then, inside that if, when you try to send the mail, check for failure:

```
  if (mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $message)){
      $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
      $firstname = $lastname = $email = $message = '';
  }
  else {
      echo "The mail command failed!!";
  }
```

Finally, give yourself some sort of indicator that there were errors, just for your testing phase.  You can remove this else (or even add better styling and keep it):

```
if ($errors == 0){

 // snip - lines of code in here removed to keep this snippet readable. this is your test and send mail logic.

}
else {
  echo "You've got $errors errors!  You need to correct them!";
}
```

With these changes, you should be able to find your issues quickly.  As I said, you can also remove some of this code (like the echo statements) once you've finished your debugging.

Good luck!

Comment: This is some very good advice! I have one question however when I select the submit button it just resets the page is this because of the way I set up my form?

Comment: The form action= decides what happens when you click the submit button.  In this case, it calls the same page again and reloads it.  Each time you click it, the web server is called again to render the page and all of the html and php code is executed again...